# Yahoo Finance API for BSE & NSE

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I have found below API for Yahoo Finance but these does not seem to be working for NSE & BSE.

http://financequotes-api.com/#singlestock

Is anybody using similar API for BSE & NSE ?

Comment: Yes I am using this API and it does not work anymore.May be yahoo stopped that.

Answer (score 2):

Try using **nsepy** if you require only price and volume information, below is the link.

https://github.com/swapniljariwala/nsepy. this is only for historical data.

Answer (score 2):

```py
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()  # <== that's all it takes :-)

# download dataframe
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("Symbol_of_the_stock.NS", period="max")

print(data)
```

Comment: what about BSE?

Comment: data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("Symbol_of_the_stock.BOM", period="max")